# Find and save href links in a html file and replace by id in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have newsletter html files. I need to capture href links in html files and save it in table. And replace the links with new tracking links followed by id.
I am able to find the links and insert in to db by following php

```
<?PHP
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);


$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
       $href = $hrefs->item($i);
       $url = $href->getAttribute('href');
       mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO urls (id, url)
VALUES ('','$url')");
       echo $url.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Here id is primary key and auto_increment. Now i need to replace those links in html file with row id of the same which i have stored. So new url should be something like this "`http://www.mysite.com/track.php?id=1`". Finally i need to generate a new html file with updated links. Please help me

Hi, i put

```
$href = 'http://mysite.com/track.php?id=' . mysqli_insert_id($con);
$dom->saveHTMLFile("temp".$y.".html");
```

after inserting into table. But i am not getting links replaced in generated html file please help

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. Replacing the id could best be done with a `preg_replace()`. Something like `$newUrl = preg_replace('/[0-9]*$/', mysqli_insert_id($con), $url);`. Put this right after your `mysqli_query`.

The regex in that preg_replace is targetted at the numbers at the end of $url. I'm hoping thats what you are going for.

Once you have the new url you can set the href attribute with it and then get the new html's output with `$dom->saveHtml();`. Write that to some new file with `file_put_contents()` or whatever method you prefer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Damien, There are lot of href links in html file. For example "http://stackoverflow.com/" and "https://www.google.co.in/". I will save these links in db with unique row ids(10 and 20 for example). Now i need to replace the links in html file with tracking url+id. Something like this http://www.mysite.com/track.php?id=10 and http://www.mysite.com/track.php?id=20.

Comment: In that case you dont even need the `preg_replace`. If you just want to replace them, just set the $href's attribute with `'mysite.com/track.php?id=' . mysqli_insert_id($con)` after your insert and get the new html with `$dom->saveHtml();`

Comment: Thanks for the help. But i am poor in php. Can you please write it completely for me?

Comment: No. I can not. Stack isnt ment to do your coding for you. We give advice and the path to your goal. It is for you to actually achieve your goal.